# cs50w wiki couldn't create a new encyclopedia entry whenever I click on submit button it does nothing

Tags: django, wiki

I was working on cs50w project1 wiki using django and when I try to create a new encyclopedia entry the submit button doesn't work.

views.py

```
def createnewform(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = CreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data['title']
        content = form.cleaned_data['content']
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
else:
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html", {'form': CreateForm()})
return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html", {'form': CreateForm()})
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>/", views.detail, name="detail"),
    path("wiki/search", views.searched_result, name="searched-result"),
    path("wiki/add", views.createnewform, name="new-form")

]
```

add.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
 {% block title %} New {% endblock%} 
 {% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'new-form' %}" method="Post">
    {%csrf_token%} {% crispy form %}
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

util.py

```
def save_entry(title, content):
    """
    Saves an encyclopedia entry, given its title and Markdown
    content. If an existing entry with the same title already exists,
    it is replaced.
    """
    filename = f"entries/{title}.md"
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        default_storage.delete(filename)
    default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(content))
```

Comment: Don't create a new form if the form is invalid (`{'form': CreateForm()}`), just return the invalid form `{'form': form}` since it has the validation errors which will get rendered, allowing you to find out the problem.

Comment: tnx, it worked when I change the form in add.html to {{form|crispy}}